# GitLab runner pulls image for every job

Tags: docker, gitlab

I have a GitLab runner using `docker` as the **executor**. My problem is, it pulls the image I have defined for every job, **which takes more time to finish the pipeline**

[image]

How can I cache the image and add a pull `policy` for the `job` or the `runner` ? Anyone please?

Answer (score 19):

The pull policy by default for a docker executor is "Always". You can use "if-not-present" pull policy to make sure it is only pulled when it is not available locally.

Read the documentation for option [here](https://docs.gitlab.com/runner/executors/docker.html#how-pull-policies-work) and how the policies work [here](https://docs.gitlab.com/runner/executors/docker.html#how-pull-policies-work)

Comment: Thanks how how should the syntax look like in `.gitlab-ci.yml` ?

Comment: pull_policy : if-not-present , the document tells where to place it in yaml

Comment: Honestly I couldn't find where to put the `pull_policy` in the yaml. They haven't mentioned where. Just said `image` and `service` but not how to properly put it

Comment: Use it in your config like 
[runners.docker]
pull_policy = "if-not-present"
. You cam check how to use here https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab-runner/-/issues/1905 (just for how to use I am referring this link)

Comment: For my docker setup, there is a peach cobbler located at:
```/var/lib/docker/volumes/gitlab-runner-config/_data/```

update the ```[runners.docker]``` section

Answer (score 15):

Check if the latest [GitLab 13.8](https://about.gitlab.com/releases/2021/01/22/gitlab-13-8-released/#configure-multiple-image-pull-policies-for-docker-executor) (January 2021) can help.

> ### Configure multiple image pull policies for Docker executor
>
> When your CI jobs are retrieving a container image from a container registry, a lost network connection can result in hours of lost development time and can negatively impact time-sensitive product deployments.
>
> To address this resiliency problem, the GitLab Runner Docker executor now supports the use of multiple values for the `pull_policy` configuration, which is defined in the GitLab Runner `config.toml` file.
>
> You can use these values, or stacked image pull policies, to configure combinations of pull policies and mitigate the impact caused by lost connectivity.
>
> For example, if you configure `pull_policy =[always, if-not-present]`, the pull policy will `always` pull the image.
> However, if the target container registry is not available, the GitLab Runner Docker executor will fall back and use the `if-not-present` policy, which means a local copy of the image will be used for that pipeline job.
>
> [image: https://about.gitlab.com/images/13_8/runner-docker-pull-policy.png -- Configure multiple image pull policies for Docker executor]
>
> See [Documentation](https://docs.gitlab.com/runner/executors/docker.html#using-multiple-pull-policies) and [Issue](https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab-runner/-/issues/26558).

---

[GitLab 15.2](https://about.gitlab.com/releases/2022/07/22/gitlab-15-2-released/#set-the-image-pull-policy-in-pipeline-configuration) (July 2022) adds:

> ### Set the image pull policy in pipeline configuration
>
> You can select different [pull policies](https://docs.gitlab.com/runner/executors/docker.html#how-pull-policies-work) for how a GitLab Runner downloads Docker images in CI/CD jobs.
>
> - `always` (the default behavior) ensures the image is always downloaded,
> - `if-not-present` downloads an image only when a local version does not exist, and
> - `never` only uses the local version (never download an image).
>
> Previously, you could define the pull policy only at the runner level. In this release we’ve added the ability to define the pull policy at the pipeline level. Use `pull_policy` in your `.gitlab-ci.yml` to define different pull policies at the job or pipeline level. This feature is not supported by shared runners.
>
> [image: https://about.gitlab.com/images/15_2/pull_policy.png -- Set the image pull policy in pipeline configuration]
>
> See [Documentation](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/yaml/#imagepull_policy) and [Issue](https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab/-/issues/21619).

Comment: Why GitLab is still trying to pull the image and failing when I am clearly specifying the pull_policy: if-not-present? Any idea? I have even tried adding this in the config.toml file, but even after all my tries it's showing me the same error, as what it showed in the bringing for default docker pull_policy: always.

Comment: @AshishPratap Not sure why: this would be a good *separate* question: make sure to mention your exact GitLab version used (are you using an on-premise one, or gitlab.com?)

Answer (score 5):

add `[[runners]] [runners.docker] pull_policy = "if-not-present"` to config.toml.

how work: https://docs.gitlab.com/runner/executors/docker.html#how-pull-policies-work

config.toml: https://docs.gitlab.com/runner/configuration/advanced-configuration.html

Comment: And, surprisingly, you don't have to cycle a service for the changes to take effect!